# Unable to load Alfresco bean

Tags: spring, alfresco

I'm hoping to make some calls to solr using Alfresco's org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrAdminHTTPClient class. However that bean `search.solrAdminHTTPCLient` does not seem to be accessible to me from the standard application context. Attempting to add a dependency and property reference for my own bean (via xml) has failed as well. Any reason this is not accessible?

```
public class MyClass extends DeclarativeWebScript implements ApplicationContextAware{
...
SolrAdminHTTPClient adminClient = (SolrAdminHTTPClient) appContext.getBean("search.solrAdminHTTPCLient");
```

Would like to avoid creating my own clients for standard solr admin queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the folder tree leading to [this file](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/afde3f58f91567b6f7eaa0bbac5e5adc38087fe0/projects/repository/config/alfresco/subsystems/Search/solr/solr-search-context.xml), I would say that bean is available in the search **SubSystem** which means it lives completely in a different context, a child context in fact.
So you need to lookup that context first, before trying to retrieve your bean !

---

**UPDATE:** I have done some digging, and I guess that your window to that child context is in [this particular bean](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/b4049c7ff000aa96e68e0818371f735d1b3fc5a6/projects/repository/config/alfresco/core-services-context.xml#L1140).
So I think you can do the following :

```
SwitchableApplicationContextFactory search = (SwitchableApplicationContextFactory)applicationContext.getBean("Search");
ApplicationContext searchCtx = search.getApplicationContext();
SolrAdminHTTPClient adminClient = (SolrAdminHTTPClient) searchCtx.getBean("search.solrAdminHTTPCLient");
```

A friend from the IRC channel has however suggested an alternative solution: 
Set up a seperate `ChildApplicationContextFactory` for Each and every bean you which to access in your child context, and he suggested you get some inspiration from [this](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/afde3f58f91567b6f7eaa0bbac5e5adc38087fe0/projects/repository/config/alfresco/activities/activities-feed-context.xml#L14).

Comment: Sounds like you're definitely taking me in the right direction. Any good examples of how to load a bean living in a different context?

Comment: This got me to the finish line! There was one small tweak to make it work:
SwitchableApplicationContextFactory search = (SwitchableApplicationContextFactory)appContext.getBean("Search");

Comment: Awesome! Bonus points for XML config example. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your feed back, I will update my anwser accordingly